# Install Vim with +clipboard support but without Gvim?

Tags: linux, os-clipboard, installing, x11

My distribution comes with a minimal version of Vim. `vim --version` returns
`-clipboard`, so the `*` and `+` registers interact (copy/paste) with the
primary and clipboard do not work.

The resources I've found suggest installing Gvim to solve that, e.g.
`vim-athena` or `vim-gtk3` packages in Debian, but I will never use it.

Can I get Vim with clipboard but with no GUI?

Comment: Have you check if the vim-X11 is avaiable for your distribution? If yes, then there is a vimx for you, which can run as a terminal version of vim with clipboard enabled. Also vimx -g can bring up the GUI.

Comment: I think you're right and that that is nox-vim in Debian. Never heard of vimx though.

Answer (score 6):

Building Vim from the source with the right flags is the general solution.

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
./configure --with-x=yes --disable-gui
```

The last command will probably raise an error message, which means
you need to install dependencies. Experienced users know how to proceed, but
if it's your first time on this, bad news is there isn't a magic solution,
you need to track down the dependencies with your package manager or
a search engine and keep trying the last line. In Debian and Ubuntu,

```
apt build-dep vim
```

will solve a great deal of those.

Once `./configure` succeeds,

```
make -j9
```

and if all the dependencies were satisfied, you can finally install it,
but first uninstall your current Vim package, if any. As root,

```
apt remove vim  #for Debian/Ubuntu
make install
```

See also: [Installing Vim help page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_90.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind having gvim installed you can run gvim in commandline mode with `gvim -v`. Then you should have a version of commandline vim able to access the keyboard.

Also if gvim is invoked as vim it will act like it was invoked as `gvim -v`, so if you do something like this:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/gvim ~/bin/vim
echo "PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

That will create a symlink to gvim under the name of vim and put it in the path before anything else. That way when vim is launched it will run gvim in commandline mode, which should clipboard support without a GUI

Finally if you have root access and this is an debian/ubuntu system you can run:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config vim
```

And then select vim.gtk3 or vim.athena

Comment: This is all correct and useful, though I would be surprised if installing gvim didn’t also install a vim link to it.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble In Gentoo, installing gvim does not install a vim link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need: have vim without gui (gvim)
I used before *vim-gnome* under ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic).
Recently, I switch to ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) and *vim-gnome* package are no more available and it seems only vim with GUI like *vim-gtk3* has clipboard option management.

I switched to *neovim* which have clipboard option (to manage with operating system clipboard), and basically have no GUI.

Comment: Neovim does not have a clipboard. It fully relies on a presence of external utilities such as xlip, xsel etc.

Comment: @Matt I used vim-gnome because it have clipboard option and I can, for example, run `"+yy` to copy a line in OS clipboard, and `"+p` to paste from OS clipboard. I would like to have the same option in vim under ubuntu Jammy (22.04) and after _apt install vim_ the version hasn’t got it. With _neovim_, I have it. Ok, I edit and add _option_

Comment: What they package in Ubuntu stays in Ubuntu. It's not about Vim/Neovim per se. Yet AFAIK the package name in Debian (and Ubuntu as well) is vim-gtk3.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer has been flagged as "Not an answer." It is hard for me to follow how this answers the original question: are you suggesting that Neovim has clipboard support even without a GUI like GVim? If so, an [edit] to clarify would help. Or perhaps you actually have a question about the Vim packages on Ubuntu (based on some comments)? In this case, please use the "Ask Question" button instead.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thank for your welcome. 
_vim-gtk3_ has GUI, so for me it is not a right answer. As many people I think, I prefer install a package than build from sources, so second answer didn’t convinced me too.
Of course, neovim is not vim but it is vim-based and seems keep very close used to vim, so I don’t understand why you tag my answer as "Not an answer".

Comment: `vim-gtk3` will just install one single binary `vim.gtk3`, which is just linked to from `/usr/bin/gvim` and only then will start as gui version, but when called as `vim`, it will not start the gui. So you can perfectly install `vim-gtk3` and just run vim with clipboard installed

Comment: yes I know that and use it if there are no other, but as the original question, I am looking for solution _without GUI_

Comment: I didn't flag your answer; I only noted that it had been flagged. I then explained difficulties I was having as a proxy for what the flagger may have meant. But I will dismiss the flag given your edits.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank for your help